# AFNetworking get request, getting NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, oauth, afnetworking, fitbit

I'm trying to make an app that connects to a web service with OAUth 1, and I'm having some trouble. Here is my method with my get request:

```
- (void)loadUserProfile
{
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[baseUrl]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"/1/user/%@/profile.json", [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"[service]" account:@"encoded_user_id"]]
                                                  parameters:nil];

    NSString *postString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_token=%@&oauth_nonce=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%@&oauth_version=%@", self.auth.consumerKey, [SSKeychain  passwordForService:@"[service]" account:@"oauth_token"], self.auth.nonce,  self.auth.signatureMethod, self.auth.timestamp, self.auth.version];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

When I call this method I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."  UserInfo=0x8efa7f0  {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[id]/profile.json,  NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[id]/profile.json,  NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x8bdb2c0 "The  network connection was lost."}
```

The resource I'm trying to get is documented here: https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API#OAuthAuthenticationintheFitbitAPI-tokenCredentials.

I havn't used `OAuth 1` before, I have never seen this error before, so I'm not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using [Simple Oauth1](https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth1). Like this:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/1/user/%@/profile.json", [SSKeychain    passwordForService:@"Fitbit" account:@"fitbit_encoded_user_id"]];
NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [OAuth1Controller preparedRequestForPath:path
                                                              parameters:nil
                                                              HTTPmethod:@"GET"
                                                              oauthToken:[SSKeychain passwordForService:@"Fitbit" account:@"fitbit_oauth_token"]
                                                             oauthSecret:[SSKeychain passwordForService:@"Fitbit" account:@"fitbit_oauth_token_secret"]];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation   JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:preparedRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonObject);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that AFHTTPClient is going out of memory at the end of your method `-loadUserProfile`.

You need to refactor this code so that the client is still retained in memory after your request.

One way to do this is to use the singleton pattern as shown in the example code in AFNetworking.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/Example/Classes/AFAppDotNetAPIClient.m#L31

Comment: Are you sure about it? I tried to make a `strong`  property of my httpClient variable and I get the same error. Strong properties shouldn't get released, right?

Comment: Tried to make a singelton as suggested, bit couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to reboot Xcode and the simulator.

The URL did work in a desktop browser and with `curl`. Realising this gave a little hint that something might be wrong with the environment.

FWIW, the Xcode version was 6.0 beta, build 6A279r.